# n-th taylor series for $f(x) = \sinh(x)$ at $a = 0$ etc.

Tags: limits, analysis, taylor-expansion

How can one find out $f^{(k)}(x)$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and the n-th taylor series $P_n(x)$ for

$f(x) = \sinh(x)$ at $a = 0$

$f(x) = x^4$ at $a = 1$

$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+2x}$ at $a = 0$

And for which x  does $R_n(x) \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$ hold?
My guess is only the last one because $x^4$ just goes towards $\infty$while the last one goes to $0$ for lim x $\to \infty$. And lim $x \to \infty$ for $\sinh(x)$ is $\infty.$

With WolframAlpha I used the taylor series calculator and I get results, but how does with work for the n-th taylor series?

Comment: The remainder is the difference between the Taylor polynomial and the function. It tending to zero means that the sequence of polynomials is getting close to the function. The function can and all non-constant polynomials go to infinity as $|x|\to \infty$, but this doesn't prevent the sequence of Taylor polynomials converging to the function. It is rather certain types of singularities of the function what prevents the remainder from tending to zero. It is actually only the third example in which the remainder doesn't tend to zero everywhere.

Comment: To compute the series of $x^4$ at $a=1$ you can expand it in powers of $x-1$. You can do this by expanding $x^4=(1+(x-1))^4=1+4(x-1)+6(x-1)^2+4(x-1)^3+(x-1)^4+0+0+...$. From that you get all Taylor polynomials truncating wherever you need. Equivalently, you can compute derivatives of $x^4$ and evaluate them at $x=1$, divide by the corresponding factorial to get the coefficients.

Comment: You can compute the coefficients of $\sinh(x)$ taking derivatives. Its derivatives alternate between $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ similar to how those of $\sin(x)$ do, but simpler because there is no negative sign involved. Alternatively, you can use that $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and that $e^{x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$. Then $\sinh(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

Comment: Finally $\frac{1}{1+2x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n2^nx^n$, which you can obtain form $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ by replacing $x$ for $-2x$.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot!